# How can I optimize this simulation including 2D list?

Tags: python, optimization

I have coded a simulation in Python which modelizes grass propagation in a world represented by a 2D grid. We start with one grass block, then the probability for an empty block to transform itself into a grass block is the number of his neighbours (including corners) containing grass over the total number of his neighbours.

The code is pretty simple. It works like this: 
User creates an object with three parameters :
the grid size (`int`), the coordinates of the first grass block (`tuple`) and the number of steps (`int`) for which the simulation will stop if reached. 
The 2D grid is `self.grille` ; a `0` represents an empty bloc where as a `1` stands for a grass block. 
While the grid is not filled (i.e. while all blocks are not equal to `1`), for all blocks in the grid, we get his neighbours (`self.get_neighbours`), then calculate the probability for it to mute into a grass block (`self.compute_proba`) and change it (or not) according it.

```
import random
from time import perf_counter

class Biome:
    def __init__(self, size, first_bloc, max_steps = 100_000):
        x,y = first_bloc
        assert 0<=x<size and 0<=y<size
        self.grille = [[0 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]
        self.grille[x][y] = 1
        self.size = size
        self.max_steps = max_steps
    
    def get_neighbours(self, coords):
        neighbours_list = []
        x,y = coords
        for i in range(-1,2):
            for j in range(-1,2):
                k, l = x+i, y+j
                if (k,l)!=(x,y) and 0<=k<self.size and 0<=l<self.size:
                    neighbours_list.append(self.grille[k][l])

        return neighbours_list
    
    def compute_proba(self, neighbours):
        return [x==1 for x in neighbours].count(True)/len(neighbours)

    def is_filled(self):
        for i in range(self.size):
            for j in range(self.size):
                if self.grille[i][j]==0:
                    return False
        return True

    def update(self, coords):
        x,y = coords

        if self.grille[x][y]==0:
            neighbours = self.get_neighbours(coords)
            p = self.compute_proba(neighbours)
            if random.random()<=p/2:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0

        return 1
    
    def simulation(self):
        steps = 0

        t_start = perf_counter()
        while not (self.is_filled() or steps>=self.max_steps):
            self.grille = [[self.update((x,y)) for y in range(self.size)] for x in range(self.size)]
            steps += 1
            
        simulation_time = perf_counter() - t_start
        return steps, perf_counter()

# for example
biome = Biome(size=10, first_bloc=(5,5), max_steps=1_000)
biome.simulation()
```

Now, I want this code to be the most optimized possible because I have to do lots of simulations in order to compute some stats.
What I have tried:

- Using scipy's `convolve2d` to get neighbours of a case in the 2D grid. It was actually much slower than what I had done.
- Using comprensions instead of `lambda` operator in `self.compute_proba`.

I don't know what else to do. Any help will be much appreciated.

---

I finally ended with something like this:

```
import random
from time import perf_counter

class Biome:
    def __init__(self, size: int, first_bloc: tuple, max_steps: int = 10_000):
        x,y = first_bloc
        assert 0<=x<size and 0<=y<size

        self.size = size
        self.first_bloc = first_bloc
        self.max_steps = max_steps
            
    def __update(self, x, y):
        if self.grille[x][y]==0:
            neighbours = [self.grille[x+i][y+j] for j in range(-1,2) for i in range(-1,2) if (i,j)!=(0,0) and 0<=x+i<self.size and 0<=y+j<self.size]
            p = neighbours.count(1)/(2*len(neighbours))
            if random.random()>p:
                return 0
            self.grass_blocks += 1

        return 1
    
    def simulation(self) -> tuple:
        self.grille = [[0 for j in range(self.size)] for i in range(self.size)]
        self.grille[self.first_bloc[0]][self.first_bloc[1]] = 1
        self.grass_blocks = 1

        steps = 0
        t_start = perf_counter()

        while not (self.grass_blocks==self.size**2 or steps>=self.max_steps):
            self.grille = [[self.__update(x,y) for y in range(self.size)] for x in range(self.size)]
            steps += 1
            
        simulation_time = perf_counter() - t_start
            
        return steps, simulation_time
```

Using a list comprehension for computing the neighbouring cells was very useful, but I still would like the code to be faster. Is it possible?

Comment: You mention SciPy, but you're not using NumPy. In particular the nested list will be slow (depending on size of course, but overall, it's slow), instead of using a NumPy two-dimensional array.

Comment: I used a numpy two-dimensional grid with scipy, but it was still much slower.

Comment: take a look at `numba` package. Profile your code, find bottlenecks and move them into compiled function. PS: running `is_filled()` in a while loop should slow you down as well. Maybe use integer counter and keep track of how many tiles are filled?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting by optimizing `get_neighbours` or just caching it. It seems the bottleneck at the moment.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def get_neighbours(self, x, y):
    neighbours_list = []
    for i in range(-1,2):
        for j in range(-1,2):
            k, l = x+i, y+j
            if (k,l)!=(x,y) and 0<=k<self.size and 0<=l<self.size:
                neighbours_list.append(self.grille[k][l])

    return neighbours_list
```

Comment: The cache has not improved significantly the speed.